# custom translate on values in laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a conditional validation on laravel 5.6:

```
'body' => 'required_if:body.*.type,left',
```

in validation.php

```
"required_if" => " :attribute is required when :other is :value",
```

and it returns a message like this: `text is required when type is left`

I want translate the word "left" to my custom word.

Is it possible to do that?

I try these:

```
'attributes' => array(
   'left' => 'left2'
),
```

or

```
'value' => array(
   'left' => 'left2'
),
```

but with no success!

Comment: Did you try to use `:input` instead of `:value`?

Comment: @NikolaGavric it return empty.